# Show index.php template instead of 404 page template

Tags: url-rewriting, page-template, 404-error

I have some posts that were permanently deleted, however, instead of wordpress returning the 404.php page template, it is returning the index.php template. In other posts, the behavior is right, but in some like this it is not

What I've done so far:

- theme change to twenty-two
- I updated the permalink structure
- I cleaned the database with the advanced database cleaner plugin.
- There is no cache

However, nothing resolved. You can see below the template shown and the correct status which is 404.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're using Cloudfront, which incorporates caching.

Comment: I also see `x-redirect-by: Permalink Manager` in the response - is that not the Permalink Manager WP plugin?